# cannot delete row from coverage with updatecursor

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, cursor, error-999999, esri-coverage-format

I am able to update without any issue or error but when I try to delete a row I'm getting an error, see below for the code and error

I can't see why it would fail.

```
import arcpy

def count_row(data):
    i = 0
    for row in data:
        i += 1

    data.reset()

    return i

arcpy.env.workspace = 'C:/Data/cea01apr'
feature = 'point'
fidfilter= 'fid = 1'

featureClassList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(feature)
fieldString = [str(x.name) for x in fieldList]

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(feature, fieldString, fidfilter) as cursorupdate:
    print('Number of rows:' + str(count_row(cursorupdate)))
    rowupdate = cursorupdate.next()
    print(rowupdate[12])

    rowupdate[12] +=  'h'
    cursorupdate.updateRow(rowupdate)

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(feature, fieldString, fidfilter) as cursorupdate:
    print('Number of rows:' + str(count_row(cursorupdate)))
    rowupdate = cursorupdate.next()

    if rowupdate:
        print(rowupdate[12])

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(feature, fieldString, fidfilter) as cursorupdate1:
    print('Number of rows:' + str(count_row(cursorupdate1)))
    for row in cursorupdate1:
        cursorupdate1.deleteRow()

raw_input('Press the <ENTER> key to exit')
```

the output is

```
C:\Data>test.py
Number of rows:1
 hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
Number of rows:1
 hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
Number of rows:1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Data\test.py", line 39, in <module>
    cursorupdate1.deleteRow()
SystemError: error return without exception set
```

I have tried this

```
arcpy.MakeTableView_management(feature, 'test')
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('test', 'NEW_SELECTION', fidfilter)
arcpy.DeleteRows_management('test')
```

but got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Data\test.py", line 41, in <module>
    arcpy.DeleteRows_management('test')
  File "C:\***\cots\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 15352, in DeleteRows
    raise e
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Failed to execute (DeleteRows).
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using `arcpy.DeleteRows_management()`?

Comment: @Berend I might need to do complex check that would be hard to implement in SQL / expression

Comment: Your code looks fine, please emphasize the fact that you're working with a coverage. I have no experience with coverages but I'm surprised that updating rows with a cursor even works. Not to mention deleting rows.

Comment: Can you manually delete a coverage feature in ArcMap? If not, you may need to convert to a file geodatabase or shapefile.

Comment: @klewis when i want to start editing from ArcMap, it say: no editable layer, coverage data source not editable

Answer (score 2):

> Coverages can be viewed in ArcMap but can only be edited in their
>   native application, ArcInfo Workstation. Export the coverage to a
>   shapefile or geodatabase feature class to edit the layer in ArcMap.

The above quote is from [ArcGIS Desktop Help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/coverage-data-source-not-editable.htm).  You can't modify coverages in ArcGIS Desktop, **including using arcpy Update Cursors**, which is why you are getting that error.  You either need to export the data to shapefile or geodatabase, or edit using ArcInfo Workstation.

**UPDATE:** In my testing I have found that the `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor()` will update values in a row, but you cannot add or remove any features.  This will be why you're getting that error only on the `deleteRow()`.